# VirtualBox Spoofing CPU Frequency

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu, spoofing

I would like to spoof as much information about my host (Windows 10 x64) on my guest (Windows 10 x64) as possible in VirtualBox. I'm already spoofing the CPU brand string using [this](/a/774596/1710421). However, applying the same strategy to spoofing CPU frequency (cpuid with 0x16 in EAX) does not seem to do the trick.

I've written a small test program in MSVC++ to print the frequency cpuid reports:

```cpp
int freq[3];
__asm {
    mov eax, 0x16
    cpuid
    mov freq[0], eax
    mov freq[1], ebx
    mov freq[2], ecx
}

for (int i : { 0, 1, 2 }) {
    std::cout << freq[i] << std::endl;
}
```

This works as expected and gets spoofed correctly, however, the guest still shows the correct information pretty much everywhere you look, suggesting there is an alternative source for it. Is it possible to identify and potentially spoof this source?

Answer (score 0):

You may modify the entire CPU profile in VirtualBox by a command such as:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "<VM name>" --cpu-profile "Intel Core i7-5600U"
```

See the article
[Where is the list of supported CPU profiles in VirtualBox?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557724/where-is-the-list-of-supported-cpu-profiles-in-virtualbox)

In the accepted answer, some types were found in
the `.rdata` section of `Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxVMM.dll`.

See also the post
[specifying the processor-type the VM sees](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=84423).

More advanced settings can be done using the `cpuidset` parameter
of the command `VBoxManage modifyvm`. See an example
[here](https://pastebin.com/s5krwbMc).
However, I haven't found documentation for the included commands.

Comment: From my limited testing it appears that cpu profiles fail to spoof the frequency as well. It [appears](https://www.virtualbox.org/browser/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/VMM/VMMR3/cpus/Intel_Core_i7_6700K.h) they're just preset data of what the answer I linked to is doing manually with the CPU brand string, besides being pretty much undocumented. `cpuidset` also seems to be doing exactly what I'm doing, just via a different (more modern?) [command parameter](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=93627).

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I remove "Nested paging" in "CPU - Hardware acceleration"
And it fixed the issue